# Finding generators for matrix group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given the group
$$ G = \left \{ \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}, a = \pm1, b \in \Bbb Z \right\}
$$
I need to find elements $x$ and $y$ in $G$ such that $G=\langle x,y \rangle$.

I've read the theory from my textbook but I don't really understand how to find $x$ and $y$. Any help would be appreciated.

I also got a hint:
first show that $H = \bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ with $b \in \Bbb Z\bigg\}$ is a cyclic group.

**Edit:**
So with the hint I found that $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is a generator for $H$, say that's my $x$. Does $G=\langle x,y \rangle$ mean that I have to find another element $y$ such that $xy$ is a generator for $G$?

Comment: Which textbook are you using?

Comment: Abstract Algebra by David Dummit and Richard Foote

Comment: The hint gives one generator already, say $x$. Now it should be easy to find another generator $y$.

Comment: So I got one generator and edited my post.

Comment: There are two choices for the entry $a$ in the matrix. . .

Comment: Yes you have to find another generator $y$, and since $x$ has $a=1$, I recommend choosing an element with $a= -1$ as $y$. (Actually any element with $a= -1$ will work, so you can't lose, but you still need to prove that $G=\langle x,y \rangle$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For  $b \in \mathbb Z$, we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^b 
=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}1 & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}-1 & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Yes, I came to this conclusion as well.